# Parsing txt file, to web scrape an image from each link on each line, with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to open a txt file, with a http link on each line, and then have python go to each link, find a specific image, and print out a direct link to that image, FOR EACH page, listed in the txt file.

But, I have no idea what I'm doing. (started python a few days ago)

Here's my current code, that, does not work...

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = open('links.txt').read().splitlines()
page = urlopen(txt)
html = page.read()
image_links = re.findall("src.\"(\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg)", html)
print image_links
```

**Update 1**:

Ok, here's what I need a little more specifically. I have a script which prints out a lot of links into a txt file, each link on it's own line. i.e.

http://link.com/1
http://link.com/2
etc
etc

what I'm trying to accomplish, at the moment is have something that opens that text file, containing those links, and run my regex that I already posted, then print the image links, it will find, in link.com/1 etc, into another text file, which should look something like

http://link.com/1/image.jpg
http://link.com/2/image.jpg

etc.

Then after that, I don't need any help, as I already have a python script which will download the images, from that txt file.

**Update 2**: Basically, what I need is this script.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://staff.tumblr.com'
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
image_links = re.findall("src.\"(\S*?media.tumblr\S*?tumblr_\S*?jpg)", html)

print image_links
```

but instead of it looking for a specific url, in the url variable, it will crawl all urls in a text file I specify, then print out the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Scrapy spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html)

Here is an example

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider


def NextURL():
    urllist =[]
    with open("URLFilename") as f:
        for line in f:
            urllist.append(line)

class YourScrapingSpider(XMLFeedSpider):

    name = "imagespider"

    allowed_domains = []

    url = NextURL()

    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):

        start_url = self.url.next()

        request = Request(start_url, dont_filter=True)

        yield request


    def parse(self, response, node):

        scraped_item = Item()
        yield scraped_item
        next_url = self.url.next()
        yield Request(next_url)
```

I am creating a spider while will read the URL from file and make the request and download the images.

For this we have to use [ImagesPipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html#topics-images-override)

It will be difficult in the starting stage but i would suggest you to learn about Scrapy. Scrapy is a web crawling framework in Python.

**Update :**

```
import re
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'

def process(url):
    myopener = MyOpener()
    #page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = myopener.open(url)

    text = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

    print(soup)

    for tag in soup.findAll('img'):
        print (tag)
# process(url)

def main():
    url = "https://www.organicfacts.net/health-benefits/fruit/health-benefits-of-grapes.html"
    process(url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

o/p

```
<img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/1430-35x35.jpg" title="Coconut Oil for Skin" alt="Coconut Oil for Skin" width="35" height="35" class="wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured" />
<img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/1427-35x35.jpg" title="Coconut Oil for Hair" alt="Coconut Oil for Hair" width="35" height="35" class="wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured" />
<img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/335-35x35.jpg" title="Health Benefits of Cranberry Juice" alt="Health Benefits of Cranberry Juice" width="35" height="35" class="wpp-thumbnail wpp_cached_thumb wpp_featured" />
<img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/wordpress-popular-posts/59-35x35.jpg"
```

**Update 2:**

```
with open(the_filename, 'w') as f:
    for s in image_links:
        f.write(s + '\n')
```

Comment: This seems a little more complex than needed for what I'm trying to do with this specific script. I have another script already which will download, I'm just trying to gather the image urls with this one. From page links I gathered with yet, another script.

Comment: Sop you want to simply get the IMAGE URL in a page ???? is my understanding correct

Comment: Just updated once more, I think I was finally able to specify what I meant!